# How to use MVC in joomla-platform

Tags: joomla-api

Where to find examples of both on the basis of joomla paltform to write an app using MVC.

- How to use the controllers?
- How to use models?
- How to use views?

> Please do not confuse this issue with Joomla CMS!
>
> This question is related to Joomla Platform 11.4+

Answer (score 1):

So I have been messing with this as well. This isn't specifically how to use the MVC, more how I set up the application around it -- that is what I first stuggled with.

It is definitely a work in progress. Since you mentioned you have written Joomla components before, this basically lets you pass a task in the format controllerclass.controllermethod like a Joomla CMS component.

One thing I did notice is that the joomla/framework (I think that's the 11.4 version) package is no longer maintained. You have to add each Joomla package individually (eg joomla/model) to get the newest version. Here is

```
index.php
configuration.php
composer.json
composer.lock
src
- Company
  - Package
    - App.php
    - Factory.php
    - Controllers
    - Interfaces
    - Models
    - Views
vendor
- composer
  ....
...
- joomla
  -  application
  ....
  - utilities
```

index.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/configuration.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Company\Package\Factory;

try {
    $app = Factory::getApplication();
    $app->execute();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

configuration.php

```
class configuration {
    /*
    App Info
    */
    public $version = '0.0.1';

    // other configuration variables
    // ...
}
```

src/Company/Package/App.php

```
<?php 

namespace Company\Package;
use Joomla\Application\AbstractWebApplication;
use Joomla\Uri\Uri;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

class App extends AbstractWebApplication {

    protected function doExecute(){

        $task = $this->input->get('task');
        $output = '';

        try {

            if (empty($task)) {

                throw new \Exception('No task submitted', 400);
            }

            if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$/i',$task)) {

                list($class,$method) = explode('.',$task);

                $controllerClassName = "Company\\Package\\Controllers\\" . ucfirst($class);

                if (!class_exists($controllerClassName)) {
                    throw new \Exception('Controller does not exist', 501);
                }

                $controller = new $controllerClassName($this->input, $this);

            } else {

                throw new \Exception("Task format not recognized", 501);
            }

            $response = $controller->$method();

            $body = $response;
            $status = 200;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            // probably need and error view instead of just dumping the error message
            $body = $e->getMessage(); 
            $status = $e->getCode();
        }

        $this->setHeader('Status', $status, true);
        $this->setBody($body);        
    }

    protected function initialise() {

        // initialize some stuff here
    }
}
```

src/Company/Package/Factory.php

```
<?php 

namespace Company\Package;

use Joomla\Registry\Registry;
use Joomla\Input;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory;

abstract class Factory {

    protected static $app;
    public static function getApplication() {

        if (isset(static::$app)) return static::$app;

        $config = static::getConfig();

        $type = 'web'; // someday setup for cli

        if ($type=='web') {
            $input = new Input\Input;
            static::$app = new App($input, $config);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("App type not supported");
        }

        return static::$app;
    }

    // only get configuration from application
    protected static $config;
    protected static function getConfig() {

        if (isset(static::$config)) return static::$config;

        $configuration = new \configuration;
        static::$config = new Registry($configuration);

        return static::$config;
    }

    protected static $db;
    public static function getDb() {

        if (isset(static::$db)) return static::$db;

        $app = static::getApplication();

        static::$db = DatabaseFactory::getDriver($app->get('drive'),[
            'host' => $app->get('host'),
            'user' => $app->get('user'),
            'password' => $app->get('pass'),
            'database' => $app->get('db'),
            'port' => $app->get('port'),
        ]);

        return static::$db;
    }
}
```